# subscript requires array or pointer type expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: c++

```
    const int max_yrs = 4;
    int taxRetrnYears[max_yrs];
    double balance[max_yrs];
    int data;
    void set(int year, double balance)
    {
        if (isEmpty() == false && data != max_yrs)
        {
            taxRetrnYears[data] = year;
            balance[data] = balance;
            data++;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if I can make an array of data type "double" but I need to store values of "double" data type in an array but it is giving me an error

Comment: Use a `std::vector<double>` instead.

Comment: but that's the requirement of my assignment
b) An array of size max_yrs to hold the balance owed or refund due on the account for each tax return year.

Comment: `data` is uninitialized, so once you get this compiling you will still have undefined behavior.

Comment: Certainly you can make an array of type `double`.  That isn't the problem. Your problem is the hiding of the id `balance`, which you are using both for the argument and the outer array. The inner one wins (and you lose).

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "balance" is colliding with your global "balance". Also, ensure to initialize your iterator "data" to zero.